# Find max element in array using PPL

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, ppl

I need to implement a function that would find the largest element in the array of floats using `ppl.h`.

I have this code, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22943575/4674270):

```
float find_largest_element_in_matrix_PPL(float* m, size_t dims)
{
    float max_element;
    int row, col;
    concurrency::combinable<float> locals([] { return INT_MIN + 0.f; });
    concurrency::parallel_for_each(size_t(0), dims * dims, [&locals](int curr)
    {
        float & localMax = locals.local();
        localMax = max<float>(localMax, curr);
    });

    max_element = locals.combine([](float left, float right) { return max<float>(left, right); });
    cout << max_element << endl;
    return max_element;
}
```

However, there's an issue with this code:

- It throws the following exception before executing:

> Error C2780   'void Concurrency::_Parallel_for_each_impl(const
>   _Random_iterator &,const _Random_iterator &,const _Function &,_Partitioner &&,std::random_access_iterator_tag)': expects 5
>   arguments - 4 provided    parp    D:\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\VC\include\ppl.h 2987
>
> Error C2780 'void Concurrency::_Parallel_for_each_impl(_Forward_iterator,const
>   _Forward_iterator &,const _Function &,const Concurrency::auto_partitioner &,std::forward_iterator_tag)': expects 5
>   arguments - 4 provided    parp    D:\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\VC\include\ppl.h 2987
>
> Error C2893 Failed to specialize function template 'iterator_traits<_Iter>::iterator_category
>   std::_Iter_cat(const _Iter &)'    parp    D:\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\VC\include\ppl.h 2987

---

1. Could you please help me with resolving that issue?
2. How can I rewrite the code to make use of `parallel_for`? (I cannot reference the array argument passed to the function in the `parallel_for` block)

Comment: You are using parallel_for parameters and the parallel_for_each function. You should probably use parallel_for not parallel_for each in this case.

Comment: @Rick thanks, I changed the code to `parallel_for` and the error was gone. But now the function returns just the index of the last element in array. Any ideas on how to make it work correctly?

Comment: @Rick sorry for misleading, it doesn't return any index, it just returns zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float SimpleTest::SimpleTestfind_largest_element_in_matrix_PPL(float* m, size_t dims)
{
    float max_element;
    concurrency::combinable<float> locals([&]{ return INT_MIN + 0.f; });
    int last= dims*dims;
    concurrency::parallel_for(0, last, [&](int curr)
    {
        float & localMax = locals.local();
        localMax = max<float>(localMax, curr);
    });

    max_element = locals.combine([](float left, float right) { return max<float>(left, right); });
    std::cout << max_element << endl;
    return max_element;
}
```

Maybe it will work